# How to create No. Series with day, month and year numbers?

Tags: dynamics-365, navision, dynamics-business-central

I want to generate No. Series in Business Central in the following format: **C220715001**

Where 22 is year number as 2022

07 is month number as July

15 is day number as today is 15-07-2022

001 is the invoice number (first generated invoice)

Is it possible to create a No. Series like this without creating 1 line per day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would require some development.